# Web API chains (On-Behalf-Of) in Azure AD B2C

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens), the on-behalf-of flow is not supported in B2C:

> Web API chains (On-Behalf-Of) is not supported by Azure AD B2C.
>
> Many architectures include a web API that needs to call another downstream web API, both secured by Azure AD B2C. This scenario is common in native clients that have a web API back end, which in turn calls a Microsoft online service such as the Azure AD Graph API.
>
> This chained web API scenario can be supported by using the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Credential grant, otherwise known as the On-Behalf-Of flow. However, the On-Behalf-Of flow is not currently implemented in Azure AD B2C.

---

Can't I just pull out the JWT from the first Web API request and pass it along to the next Web API?  I know technically, I can, but is there a reason I wouldn't want to?

This approach would only work if both Web API's are configured for the same B2C App.  Maybe that is the difference.  Is the documentation referring to 2 separate B2C apps maybe?

---

Reference: [Access the JWT bearer token when using the JWT middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnetcore-jwt-saving-bearer-token-as-claim/)

Comment: No, you shouldn't use one app for 2 real apps. In such case, the first app (frontend) has no limits to access the final resource. On-behalf-of flow makes that impossible. Frontend can access only some web-ap - and only that web-api can contact the final resource.

Answer (score 7):

The OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow is related to a first resource, "https://resourceserver1", receiving an access token from a client; then exchanging this access token for another access token for access by the delegated identity to a second resource, "https://resourceserver2" without any user interaction; and then sending that access token to the second resource.

[This Azure AD documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) explains the On-Behalf-Of flow.

Given this, two different applications are necessary for two different resources, which in turn can require two different scopes.

You can vote for this feature at [B2C Support for on-behalf-of flow](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/86d396da-b125-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789).

Comment: Hi Chris - appreciate the answer.  What about this part though: "Can't I just pull out the JWT from the first Web API request and pass it along to the next Web API? I know technically, I can, but is there a reason I wouldn't want to?"

Comment: FYI the linked Azure feedback item for voting appears to now be about OAuth2 Client Credentials flow (although the url still mentions on-behalf-of flow?).

The best existing feedback item I could find for voting for on-behalf-of flow is https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/34950694-add-support-to-azure-ad-b2c-for-the-on-behalf-of-f

Comment: You wouldnt want to because the APIs are different and have different security needs. If you re-use your JWTs, effectively all your APIs appear to be the same one to Azure AD from a security point of view. You can do this, but you shouldn't. You should be able to differentiate your services, and their scopes/permissions. Just like you don't name every class in your project Class1.cs

Comment: The link to user voice isnt 100% correct. Its not for on-behalf-of-flow - its for Client Credentials flow...

Comment: Fortunately now the link is dead. thanks msft

Comment: i can't believe this is still not supported today